# Log4J Bottom Line Log

Tags: java, log4j

**Log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\ParallelKMeansProject\\logs\\log.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**Main.java**

```
SimpleKMeans model = new SimpleKMeans();
model.setNumClusters(K);
model.buildClusterer(data);
log.info(model);
```

**log.log**

> *Cluster 0: 41.051205,28.808497 Cluster 1: 41.055391,28.785407 Cluster 2: 41.054838,28.802617 Cluster 3: 41.022421,28.788169 Cluster 4:
>   41.024494,28.784099 Cluster 5: 41.018659,28.787669 Cluster 6: 41.040879,28.753359*

**My Problem**

Log file is *txt extension. These logs are written long in the file side by side. I want to print the bottom line. As follows;

Cluster 0: 41.051205,28.808497

Cluster 1: 41.055391,28.785407

Cluster 2: 41.054838,28.802617

How can I change log properties  %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

Comment: In which environment you created this log and in which environment you'are trying to view it, is it the same?

Comment: I use the API and it prints the logs. I want the logs to be printed at the bottom.



I need this fix. ->  %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

Comment: My bad. I mean if you create it in Linux and view it in windows could cause this issue.

Comment: I use windows, everything is working locally

Comment: I would guess that `model.toString()` return a single line. Why not changing it there?

Comment: How can I change, absoluetly return single line. So log4j write side by side.

Comment: Can you post the toString method？